# How to prevent form from sending when there are alerts showing? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a contactus form on my website, and I have few js functions that check if the values are valid or not. What currently happens is - the functions do work, they check what they are supposed to, and the alert shows as well - But after all the alerts showed, it still submits the form.
I tried to use the Prevent method, and the window.back.history but none worked...
How can I fix it?

JavaScript part:

```
<script>
   function validateForm1() {
        var firstname = document.forms["contactus"]["fname"].value;
        if (firstname == "") {
          alert("Please provide your first name");
          return false;
          e.preventDefault();
          window.history.back();
            }
        }
  
        document.getElementById("gender").addEventListener('click',checkradio);

        function checkradio() {
        if(document.getElementById("genderm").checked == false && document.getElementById("genderf").checked == false && document.getElementById("gendero").checked == false  ){
            alert("Please select your gender");
            return false;
            e.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();}
        }

        function checkbox(){
        if (document.querySelector('#cbr:checked') == null){
            alert("Please choose a subject");
            return false;
            e.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();
        }

        function agecheck(){
        var x = document.forms["contactus"]["age"].value;
        var y = 18;
        if(x<y)
        {
            alert("Please submit the form only if you're 18 yo");
            return false;
            e.preventDefault();
            window.history.back();
        }
        }

    }
        
        </script>
```

My HTML part uses the submit method and links to:

```
        <form id="contactus" name="contactus" action="http://jkorpela.fi/cgi-bin/echo.cgi" onsubmit="validateForm1();checkbox();checkradio();agecheck()" style="float:right;text-align: right; direction: rtl;">
```

Comment: Try to move the `return false;` after the `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: was just about to suggest the same as above, more `e.preventDefault()` before the return or move the return to just before the end of the curly

Comment: so i was going to post a clean version of you js, your actual problem is you dont have access to e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can put 'return' in 'onsubmit'.

```
<script>
    function validateForm1() {
        var firstname = document.forms["contactus"]["fname"].value;

        if (firstname == "") {
            alert("Please provide your first name");
            return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("genderm").checked == false && document.getElementById("genderf").checked == false && document.getElementById("gendero").checked == false) {
            alert("Please select your gender");
            return false;
        }

        if (document.querySelector('#cbr:checked') == null) {
            alert("Please choose a subject");
            return false;
        }

        var x = document.forms["contactus"]["age"].value;
        var y = 18;

        if (x < y) {
            alert("Please submit the form only if you're 18 yo");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form id="contactus" name="contactus" action="http://jkorpela.fi/cgi-bin/echo.cgi" onsubmit="return validateForm1();" style="float:right;text-align: right; direction: rtl;"></form>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your form for each you can use the required tag so they always have to input something into the field.

For example

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
```